# Function within function in R does not work

Tags: r, function, global-variables, environment

I have defined the following functions:

```
where_condition_SQL<-
 function(table,selected_columns,where_conditions) {  
    new_table<-sqldf(sprintf("select %s from %s where %s",
                            as.character((selected_columns)),
                            deparse(substitute(table)),
                            as.character((where_conditions))))   
     return(new_table) }

  select_category_amounts <- function(
     input_table,selected_columns,category,category_column){
     new_table<-where_condition_SQL(input_table,
             selected_columns=as.character(selected_columns),
                      where_conditions=sprintf( "%s='%s'",
                                                 as.character(category_column), 
                                                 as.character(category)) )     return(new_table) }
```

When I try to run the second function by:

```
select_category_amounts(second_table,"*","Reservas","categoria2")
```

then it does not recognize the second_table and give me the following error:

```
Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : 
no such table: input_table
```

I suppose that this is some issue about enviroments but I do not get the point. Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Comment: Please review [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `eval` instead of `deparse` in your first function, and pass the name of the table as a string. This way, you can get the content of the variable `table` in your first function:

```
where_condition_SQL<-
  function(table,selected_columns,where_conditions) {  
    new_table<-sqldf(sprintf("select %s from %s where %s",
                             as.character((selected_columns)),
                             eval(table),
                             as.character((where_conditions))))   
    return(new_table) }

select_category_amounts("second_table","*","Reservas","categoria2")
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : 
  no such table: second_table
```

With `eval`, you can also pass the name of the table as an object:

```
second_table <- "mytable"
select_category_amounts(second_table,"*","Reservas","categoria2")

Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : no such table: mytable
```